# Installing Source Control with Lotus Notes Designer 8.5.3 GEF SDK missing

Tags: svn, xpages

We want to use subversion as source control for our Lotus Notes Applications. Niklas Heidloff published a documentation how to add the necessary applications to our 8.5.3 Designers to make a connection to the repository

http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/09152011024951AMNHEA28.htm

Unfortunately someone changed the folder for the GEF SDK resource on the eclipse download page. The needed 3.6.2 SDK was moved from update releases to an archive folder. We tried to modify the associates.xml file to use the new archive folder, but the installation still failed as it still tries to get the sdk from the update folder.

Can you assist in that issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Until we have the full update site on openNTF (if we have the permission), here some instructions to build for your own use a custom update site.

- Get the GEF 3.6.2 Runtime Package -> http://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/
- Open the Eclipse (testet with Helios & Indigo Release) with a blank (or new Workspace)
- Import the GEF 3.6.2 Features & Plugins (these are 2 Steps)
- Do the same with this update sites:
  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/subversive/0.7/builds/Subversive-incubation-0.7.9.I20100512-1900.zip
  http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/builds/Subversive-connectors-2.2.2.I20100512-1900.zip
  ----> SHORT TIP: extract the .jar Files under features, otherwise you couldnot import them
- Now you have a Workspace full of features and plugins
- Build an update site project and assign alle features from your workspace to this update site

Hope this helps!

Update: A new Project with the full updatesite is relaesed unter openNTF -> http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8RJASZ

Answer (score 1):

I heard this question this week five times. I don't know what exactly has changed but one person told me he would want to put the complete update site on OpenNTF. I'll also point him to this post.