# Source Control in Lotus Domino Designer

Tags: eclipse, svn, mercurial, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We have been using Domino on a large project for years without any real source-control (other-than server backups).  So, I was rather pleased when I noted the latest Designer 8.5.3 has potential integration with SVN.

I was unable get SVN working just by following the [original instructions](http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/09152011024951AMNHEA28.htm) for as already [noted on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128812/installing-source-control-with-lotus-notes-designer-8-5-3-gef-sdk-missing) the update sites have moved.  The [solution posted on OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8RJASZ), only half worked, with Domino still croaking at GEF, Mylyn and some other missing plugins.  After finding and installing them,  I still do not seem to have source-control integration.

What I have now is the ability to create on-disk projects but I do not seem to have any source-control features.  I was expecting to see menu items for commit, update, revert …etc – is this how it works in Domino?

I can of course create a repository to commit the on-disk project to but I was hoping for integration inside of Domino.  Whilst having years of experience in programming I’m a novice with Eclipse.  I assume that I’ve done something wrong with installing the plugins?  it was certainly a complicated process trying track down missing plugins.

Has anyone tried this recently and succeeded? What files do I need to install, setting tweak, …etc, to ensure this works?  I’m happy to  install my Designer fresh and follow a list of instructions.

Also, am I understanding how the integration works?  Will I get command integration within Designer or do I have to work separately with the on-disk projects?  I was really hoping for this be easy to integrate into normal workflow so I can convert the team to using it (adding  too many extra or complicated steps is unlikely to create a conversion).

I posted a screenshot of my installed plugins in case this is helpful.

[image]

**Mercurial?** As an aside, has anyone used Mercurial instead of SVN with Designer?  I would rather use Hg as I’m using this for related Dojo projects and will be easier for the team to use one system.  However, I will settle for SVN as any source-control is better than non.

Comment: Please note, I was not going to the correct menu.  SVN should work if follow the instructions already supplied on Stackoverflow (linked in my question).  I needed to setup the repository by selecting the "Team" menu and "Share project...".  See answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** *This is answer is now out-of-date.  It is useful in that it should point users in the right direction but it isn't really a working answer anymore.  I no-longer develop on Lotus Notes so I cannot update it to a current solution.*

I managed to figure this out eventually but will post the solution, just in case anyone else has the same trouble.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471700/source-control-in-lotus-domino-designer/13477058#13477058) by [Per Henrik Lausten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785061/per-henrik-lausten) was very helpful as it showed me the route to follow through the menus. The main problem is that I'm not used to how Eclipse works so I didn't realise you had to go to the *"Team"* menu and *"Share Project"* after creating the on-disk project.  When I did this I discovered that both SVN and CVS were already available.

I found that SVN did not like the **file://** protocol (perhaps a windows issue?)  Since, I could not arrange for an SVN server on our network, I decided to go down the Mercurial route.  This was better for us as our other projects are stored in Mercurial.

**Setting-up Mercurial with Lotus Designer 8.5.3:**

1. In Domino preference (File -> Preferences), set: *Enable Eclipse Plugins* in the Domino Designer section to **ticked**.
2. Also in the preferences set: *Use Binary DXL for source control operations* to **unticked** (File -> Preferences, Domino Designer -> Source Control).  Without this ticked I was not getting text for my Lotusscript agents and it would be difficult to compare changes.
3. Go to File -> Application -> Install:

   - Select *Search for new features to install* and click **Next**.
   - Click **Add Remote Location** button
   - Add the url: http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable/ and give it a suitable name
   - Once you've added this, ensure it is ticked in the location list and click **Finish**
   - Design will then search for updates and give you a list.  Untick *"Only show latest version of a feature per update site"*
   - Tick **MercurialEclipse 1.6** from MercurialEclipse Stable Releaes.  I found that the latest version does not work, however a previous [Stackoverflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359476/mercurial-setup-for-lotus-domino-designer-8-5-3) indicates that version 1.6 does work.
   - Click finish and allow it to install.
   - You will be asked to approve various plugins and then to restart.
   - MercurialEclipse, should now be installed!
4. To start using Mercurial with a Domino Application:

   - Right-click the application in the Applications tab, select: Team Development -> Set Up Source Control for this Application.
   - Give the project a name and choose a location for the project to be stored.
   - Designer will then do a DXL export of the database to your chosen location. A **Navigator tab** will appear next to Applications.
   - Right-click your new disk-project in the Navigator and select: Team -> Share Project...
   - Select Mercurial from the Repository types and allow Designer to create the repository.
   - You should now have access to various Mercurial functions via the Team menu. (You need to make your first commit.
5. When you make changes you want to commit to source-control, you need to:

   - Right-click the application and choose: Team Development -> Sync with on disk project...
   - Go to the Navigator tab and right-click your on-disk project, selecting team.

Most of the above steps should be obvious but decided to post full details in case anyone struggled like I did with Eclipse and how to use it properly.  Once I figured it out, it really was quite easy.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, if your answer to your own question solves your problem, you can "self-approve" your answer. Just improves clarity of content on SO. In fact it's encouraged. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: The link is not working anymore, and if you use the "new" link https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/ for the plugin, the installation of the Versions 1.6 or 1.7.1 still try to contact resources on above URL and the installation fails. All Domino Designer documentation and youtube videos refer to the old URL... How can I install the plug-in?

Comment: Hi Edwin, I am no longer developing on Domino so difficult for me to update this answer. Maybe post a new question on SO and hope someone answers or post to notes.net and hope someone answers there. If you get an answer would love to update mine answer here to help others like yourself. However, without a working Domino install for me to test on I cannot really research  this myself.

Comment: Okay, no worries, it was a long shot to post on such an old question :-)

Comment: @Squirrelintraining Thanks, have done that.  I think it is still useful to some people in that it might give them half an answer.  Hopefully, someone will post a new answer that works.

Comment: @StephenSimpson source controll in domino just sucks balls. It appears to be buggy, tedious and related to your designar install instance wether it is more work or allot more work.

Comment: @Squirrelintraining Yes, source control is rubbish in domino, many things are.

Comment: @StephenSimpson Do you know any1 that seriously uses sourcecontroll in domino?

Comment: @Squirrelintraining Yes, we used to (when I answered this question).  However, as you have probably discovered it is worse than rubbish.  It gave us some fallback on code changes.  It was useful infrequently but was worth us having for those times when it was needed. If you are looking for the usual benefits of git (or other SCM) then Domino cannot provide it, this is basically a better backup system and way of logging changes.

Answer (score 6):

Keith Strickland has created a series of blog posts on using source control with DDE. They might help you:

- Keith Strickland: source control in DDE part
  1: http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=B236F39DEAF6C52F85257A72001157BF
- Keith Strickland: source control in DDE part
  2: http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=B5D76A6DA163DCB585257A7C004802B6
- Keith Strickland: source control in DDE part
  3: http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=C2C46D278948A24985257A7D0055D25E

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Whilst it wasn't 100% what I was looking for (as it was for using Designer with Git Repositories), it really helped a lot.  I've upvoted you as it will help anyone wanting to use Git + the links helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: links broken, new URL: http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=B236F39DEAF6C52F85257A72001157BF