# Domino/Notes Source control with rational Jazz

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I would like to know if its possible with the new source control possibilities since 8.5.3 if we could use Rational Jazz as the source control environment.

Comment: It would be best to ask directly in the jazz.net forum, as in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/8480/support-for-lotus-domino-8

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471700/source-control-in-lotus-domino-designer?lq=1

tl;dr - you can convert your nsf into a file file equivalent, then any scm can import this. I'd recommend you search for an eclipse scm plugins as someone's probably written a plugin for jazz. I've already tested source control against TFS, SVN and git they've worked a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not as integrated as you want it to be. 
First import your Domino project into RTC by using Project Explorer, right click/Import. Choose "File system" and specify the location of your On-Disk project.
Then you can upload your code into an existing repository workspace.

So you will still have to use the Rational user interface for source code control.

I noticed that "see pending changes" wont work as expected in RTC3.0.1. It will take some seconds before a refresh has any effect. So if you cant see your changes in RTC, wait a few seconds, then hit refresh.

Reminder to self: should create a blog post about using RTC with Domino Designer

Comment: Consider not leaving notes for your future self, otherwise, welcome to Stack Overflow