# Source control on Lotus Notes documents

Tags: lotus-notes

It is easy to enable Source Control on a Lotus Notes database - this will maintain an on disc copy of all the design elements in the database. But, is it possible to include documents as well? In our designs we have a lot of documentation, keywords and translations stored in Lotus Notes documents in the database - can we include these documents in the source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this link about Designer + Mercurial

[Source Control in Lotus Domino Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471700/source-control-in-lotus-domino-designer)

The process is very interesting: Domino designer downloads an Eclipse equivalent project using DXL. Then Mercurial access to that project and do its magic.

The solution would have to be similar, because you can export documents as text using DXL too. I think that this would be the process:

- An agent downloads at HH:00 hours all documents using DXL to a specific folder
- A Linux cron/Windows scheduled task, at JJ:00 hours calls Mercurial and do the commit.

I'm not a Mercurial expert, but so far as I read, I think that process would work.